# Pseudo alignment ::after multiline list items

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add a pseudo element after each list item.

The issue is that I have 2 lines per list item and I want the pseudo element to be aligned after the longest line, which is not always the second line, after which the pseudo element is placed.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.title {
  background-color: #5BC8F7;
}
.title .first {
  display: block
}
.title::after {
  content: "pseudo";
  background-color: #FFBA10;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="title"><span class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor </span> sit amet.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title"><span class="first">Lorem </span>ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Here is a codepen with the code above](http://codepen.io/anefkapan/pen/ALqjxg)

[Here is the desired result](http://imgur.com/a/7lt9N)

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to measure the amount of characters in a line with CSS. You could use JavaScript instead. Here is an example in jQuery to create a similar result, although it is not exactly a pseudo element.

```
$('.title').each(function() {
var x = $(this).text().length;
var y = $(this).find('.first').text().length;
var highlight = '<span class="highlight">highlight</span>'

if((x-y) > y) {
    $(this).append(highlight)
}
else {
    $(this).find('.first').append(highlight)
} });
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYHKZ.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it has not to do with the amount of characters but with each line's lenght in px. It is possible a line to has less characters and has higher width at the same time. Anyway, it seems I will not avoid JavaScript.